# "unexpected end of stream on http" when connecting to expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

I set up my development environment for React Native following the instructions here:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

When connecting to the expo server on my mobile phone using expo go I get the "something went wrong error", with the log showing:

```
Uncaught error: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://192.168.86.40:8081
```

I'm able to connect to another machine in my network though the I set up the same as the first one for native react development. I've also verified that the expo port is open:

```
nc -zv  192.168.86.40 8081
Connection to 192.168.86.40 8081 port [tcp/tproxy] succeeded!
```